# Как добавить в селектор итемы?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет. Есть

```
<select id="start" onchange="calcRoute();">
      <option value="*****">*****</option>
      <option value="*****">******</option>
      <option value="******">******</option>
```

Как через Jquery или Js добавть к нему еще опций или удалить ????Благодарю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавить можно так:

```
var $_container = $('#start');
$_container.append('<option value="*****">*****</option>');
```

Удалить:

```
var $_element = $_container.find('option[value = ******]');
$_element.remove();
```

Comment: а допустим у еня есть некая переменная и я её хочу поставить в значение ,как тогда быть ?

Comment: Можно так: $_container.append('<option value=' + value + '>*****</option>'); где value - ваша переменная

Comment: щас попробую)посмотрим )

Comment: Все ок работает )